# JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray Volley librerary

Tags: android, arrays, json

```
----------
articulo: {
precio_competencia_a: null,
grupo_conceptual: "BALERINA",
estilo: "32501 ",
color: "PLATA",
precio: "529.00",
marca: "Flexi",
id_marca: "15",
concepto: "POR DEFINIR CALZADO DAMA",
id_grupo_conceptual: "7",
id_linea: "1",
precio_sin_descuento: "529.00",
acabado: "PIEL",
precio_competencia_b: null,
precio_competencia_c: null,
logo: "logo3.png",
foto: "4030/006966/4030_006966_170.jpg",
id_cadena: "4030",
codigo: "006966 ",
linea: "CALZADO MUJER"
},
```

Below is my code:

```
public List<PostProductos> parseJson(JSONObject jsonObject){
    // Variables locales
    List<PostProductos> posts = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray jsonArray= null;

    try {
        // Obtener el array del objeto

        jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("articulo");


        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

            try {

                JSONObject Object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.println(Object.getString("marca"));;



               PostProductos post = new PostProductos(

                        Object.getString("marca")
                       );

                //posts.add(post);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "nel: "+ e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return posts;
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"precio_competencia_a":null,"grupo_conceptual":"BALERINA","estilo":"32501     ","color":"PLATA","precio":"529.00","marca":"Flexi","id_marca":"15","concepto":"POR DEFINIR CALZADO DAMA","id_grupo_conceptual":"7","id_linea":"1","precio_sin_descuento":"529.00","acabado":"PIEL","precio_competencia_b":null,"precio_competencia_c":null,"logo":"logo3.png","foto":"4030\/006966\/4030_006966_170.jpg","id_cadena":"4030","codigo":"006966    ","linea":"CALZADO MUJER"} at articulo of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "articulo" object is an Object and not an Array.
JSON objects starts with { and closes with }.
JSON arrays starts with [ and closes with ].

This will work:

```
// Obtener el array del objeto
if (jsonObject.has("articulo") && jsonObject.get("articulo") instanceof JSONObject) {
  JSONObject articulo = jsonObject.getJSONObject("articulo");
}
```

If you need JSONArray:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
if (jsonObject.has("articulo") && jsonObject.get("articulo") instanceof JSONObject) {
  jsonArray.put(jsonObject.getJSONObject("articulo"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your JSON response, it seems that `articulo` is a `JSONObject` but not a `JSONArray`.

`articulo` will be `JSONArray` (enclosed in square brackets), if it was something like this:

```
articulo: [
{
....
},
{
....
}
]
```

`articulo` is `JSONObject` (enclosed in curly braces), as it is something like this:

```
articulo: {
    ....
    }
```